# How to document RFC3339 date-time input in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Using OpenAPI 3.0, I need to document how to provide an RFC3339 Date Time JSON input with an HTTP POST to my API endpoint.

The example date-time format will look like this:

```
"2021-06-20T01:02:03+00:00"
```

Consulting the Swagger documentation I have tried various methods including the following:

```yaml
          content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        datetime:
                            type: date
                            pattern: /([0-9]{4})-(?:[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):(?:[0-9]{2}):(?:[0-9]{2})+(?:[0-9]{2}):(?:[0-9]{2})/
                            example: "2021-06-20T01:02:03+00:00"
                        example: "2021-06-20T01:02:03+00:00"
```

---

```yaml
         content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        datetime:
                            type: string
                            description: RFC3339 Datetime to set
                            format: date-time
                            example: "2021-06-20T01:02:03+00:00"
```

Neither work - an both render the following errors in Swagger UI from the browser:

[image]

[image]

How do I correctly document this RFC3339 DateTime input in OpenAPI 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is correct and is rendered correctly in https://editor.swagger.io - as shown below.

The first example is invalid, it results in a rendering error because the second `example` keyword (the one alongside `datetime`) is not expected at this position.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had an extra 'content' tag. This helped me see it.